# Visa requirements when connecting through Russia on separate tickets?

Tags: visas, air-travel, transit-visas, russia

Similar questions have been asked, but couldn't find the information for Vladivostok, specifically.

I'm trying to find the cheapest way to get from Seoul to Barcelona during a very busy time of the year.

I found relatively cheap return tickets from Seoul to Vladivostok. I also found a cheap return ticket from Vladivostok to Barcelona.

Is it possible to transit from one flight to the other without having to go through customs? That is, without Russian visa?

I will have carry-on luggage only.

If not possible through Vladivostok, I could do the same through Beijing, but it will be a bit more expensive and the flight hours are less interesting. And more risky as time between flights is shorter, and I assume I won't be protected if any delay occurs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Timatic](https://www.united.com/web/en-US/apps/vendors/default.aspx?i=TIMATIC) has the following to say on Russian transit:

> Transiting without a visa is possible for:
>
> Holders of onward tickets for a max. transit time of 24 hours.
>
> TWOV is not applicable if the airport of arrival is different from the airport of departure within the same Russian city.
>
> **There are no transit facilities available at** Khabarovsk (KHV), Krasnodar (KRR), Mineralnye Vody (MRV), Rostov-on-Don (ROV), Sochi (AER), **Vladivostok (VVO)** and Yuzhno Sakhalinsk (UUS). Passengers are required to clear Immigration and Customs.

Therefore you will need a visa for a transit in Vladivostok. Transiting other airports (such as Moscow or St. Petersburg) should be fine however, as long as it's less than 24 hours.